# Precompute lighting on one primitive in opengl and then use on other primitives

Tags: opengl, jogl

Say I have two triangles in an opengl 3d setup, with a specific light source. The first triangle:

```
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)

glMaterialfv(GL_FRONT, GL_AMBIENT_AND_DIFFUSE, color)
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
glNormal3fv(n1)
glVertex3f(p1)
glVertex3f(p2)
glVertex3f(p3)
glEnd()
```

Now I draw the second triangle, at a different position

```
glBegin(GL_TRIANGLES)
glNormal3fv(n2)
glVertex3f(p4)
glVertex3f(p5)
glVertex3f(p6)
glEnd()
```

but I want the light applied to this triangle AS IF it was located and had the same normal vector as the first triangle. Obviously it is easy to just change the normal vector, but it seems that I can not change the apparent position relative to the light source without also changing the true position of the triangle. Also, since the light properties of my 3d world will not change in time, I would like to precompute this in the beginning and then store it. Any tips?

Why I want to do this: essentially the vision of the player seeing the 3d world will be distorted in some way, such that the position of all 3d objects will change. However this should then not affect the color of the primitives as computed after applying a light source.

Comment: "*the vision of the player seeing the 3d world will be distorted in some way, such that the position of all 3d objects will change.*" If you're distorting the vision of the player by distorting the position of objects in the world, why are you also not distorting the position of the *light*? It's in the world too.

Comment: Of course the light source location must also be distorted, but if I only use diffuse+ambient light, the location of the viewer with respect to the source is not important(right?). So the light only computes the color/appearance of certain objects, and I would like to "save" this appearance from one object and then apply it to another object to be able to implement the distortion of the light properly.

Comment: Why not just move the light?

Comment: because I would need to move the light for every triangle I draw, which seems very inefficient. It seems strange to me if I can not retrieve the information opengl has computed on one triangle and then use that information on other triangles, seems like a very basic operation.

Comment: "*seems like a very basic operation*" It's only "basic" because you want to do it. From the point of view of OpenGL, the GPU, and pretty much everything that deals with actually rendering, what you want represents information moving in the *wrong direction*. Information goes from your application, through the rendering pipeline and to the screen. It doesn't stop half-way and loop around. What you want would be difficult to do with actual *shaders*. OK, what you want would actually be *trivial* to do with shaders, but not the way you want to do it.

Comment: Wait, it would be difficult or trivial with shaders? If it is trivial to do with shaders, I will look into that. Otherwise I might just compute the light effects myself outside the gpu.

Comment: You should probably doing the distortion in shaders to begin with. Also, with shaders you are free to pass in both the distorted and undistored coordinates and use one to calculate the lighting and the other to calculate the position. This is rather easy if you want to keep the primitve outdated OpenGL lighting model that you are currently using (i.e. no shadow casting).

Comment: Alright, I will look into shaders then. I am quite new to opengl and have not bothered learning shaders yet so I guess now is as good time as any to start! If you have any other tips, like where to start learning shaders for this purpose, it would be greatly appreciated!